# When I read some questions on Stackoveflow, some of them begins with "So"

Tags: questions

Here are some typical example question which I have seen began with **"So"**.

1. So I have write this code so far.
2. So I have this code here.
3. So here is my code
4. So I'm new in Java.

So I actually don't know if it's correct to begin a question with **"So"**?

Comment: So, what would make you think it wouldn't?

Comment: for me it sounds not correct to begin a question with `so` but i don't know if it is actually correct or not

Comment: [One definition of the word _so_](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=so&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) is: _Used to preface a remark or signal a new subject_.

Comment: I edit out as many as I find....

Comment: Usually on SO, one does not launch directly into one's question, but describes the surrounding context, show code gists, etc. which makes using "so", as in "So here is the situation..." appropriate, unless right from the beginning "So, here is my question..." is used, which will usually get responses of "Please show us your code." Using "So here is my question..." would be appropriate after the context is laid out as in "So *finally*, here is my question..."

Comment: "So" at the beginning of a discussion, when it doesn't mean "therefore" or "consequently" is a filler word, like "like".  Some people pepper their speech with "like" when it has no meaning except to fill a silence, like "um" or "uh".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In formal registers, *so* introducing a clause or sentence, with the approximate meaning “consequently” or “therefore”, is common and unremarkable. Traditional grammar understands this *so* to be a conjunction, and it does act to relate consecutive sentences; but syntactically it is probably better understood as a clausal modifier.

Note that this *so* necessarily looks backward to an immediately previous utterance, since it announces an inference to be drawn from that. When you find it at the beginning of a discourse—as in your examples, for instance, where it introduces the Question which leads the page—you're dealing with something quite different. This is *so* employed as a colloquial [*discourse marker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker): a verbal signal that a new topic or speaker is entering the conversation, rather like clearing your throat loudly.

This use of *so* is strictly colloquial and should **not** be followed in formal writing. Markers of this sort are held to be superfluous in this sort of discourse, where it is assumed that the reader is unremittingly attentive to the development of your argument.

Elementary and high school teachers have for more than a century been especially severe on this use, and have imposed it as a 'rule' that “*So* should not be used at the beginning of a sentence.” This is quite untrue; it’ a ‘baby rule’ designed to stamp out ***misuse*** of *so*, because in the US, *so* is a favorite narrative structuring device of young storytellers—I've heard long narratives in which almost every sentence began with *so*. So [*←proper use!*] teachers are watchful for its occurrence, and eager to eliminate it from academic writing.